# How do I switch players on button click?

Tags: java

I have one button: Gooi
I have 2 players that can throw a dice after eachother. So player 1 gets to throw, then player 1, then player 2. I don't know how to do that. I don't know if I should use a while or for loop to check wich player's turn it is.

My code:

```
package Opdrachten;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class spel extends JPanel {
private JButton knop;
private boolean geklikt, player1, player2;
private JLabel speler1, speler2, plekOpBord, gegooid, bijzonderheid;
Random rand = new Random();
int waardeP1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
int waardeP2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
int optelP1 = 0;
int optelP2 = 0;

public spel() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    knop = new JButton("Gooi");
    knop.addActionListener(new KnopHandler());
    knop.setBounds(20,20, 100,20);
    speler1 = new JLabel("Speler 1");
    speler2 = new JLabel("Speler 2");
    speler1.setBounds(20, 50, 50, 50);
    speler2.setBounds(20, 80, 50, 50);
    gegooid = new JLabel("");
    gegooid.setBounds(140, 5, 150, 50);
    plekOpBord = new JLabel("Plek op het bord");
    plekOpBord.setBounds(140, 35, 100,50);
    bijzonderheid = new JLabel("Bijzonderheid");
    bijzonderheid.setBounds(260, 35, 100,50);


    add(knop);
    add(gegooid);
    add(speler1);
    add(speler2);
    add(plekOpBord);
    add(bijzonderheid);



}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);


    if(geklikt) {
        optelP1 += waardeP1;
        g.drawString("Speler 1 " + " heeft " + waardeP1 + " gegooid", 150,40);
        g.drawString(""+optelP1, 175, 85);
    }

    if (optelP1 == 3) {
        g.drawString("Bokkesprong", 260, 85);
    }
    if (optelP1 == 6) {
        g.drawString("Brug", 260, 85);
    }
    if (optelP1 == 15) {
        g.drawString("Vogelkooi", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 19){
        g.drawString("Hotel", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 26){
        g.drawString("Dobbelsteenvakje", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 31){
        g.drawString("Put", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 39){
        g.drawString("Trap", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 42){
        g.drawString("Labyrint", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 52){
        g.drawString("Gevangenis", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 58){
        g.drawString("Graf", 260, 85);
    }
    if(optelP1 == 63){
        g.drawString("Zonsondergang", 260, 85);
    }


    if(geklikt) {
        optelP2 += waardeP2;
        //g.drawString("Speler 1 " + " heeft " + waardeP2 + " gegooid", 150,40);
        g.drawString(""+optelP2, 175, 110);
    }

    if (optelP2 == 3) {
        g.drawString("Bokkesprong", 260, 110);
    }
    if (optelP2 == 6) {
        g.drawString("Brug", 260, 110);
    }
    if (optelP2 == 15) {
        g.drawString("Vogelkooi", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 19){
        g.drawString("Hotel", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 26){
        g.drawString("Dobbelsteenvakje", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 31){
        g.drawString("Put", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 39){
        g.drawString("Trap", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 42){
        g.drawString("Labyrint", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 52){
        g.drawString("Gevangenis", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 58){
        g.drawString("Graf", 260, 110);
    }
    if(optelP2 == 63){
        g.drawString("Zonsondergang", 260, 110);
    }
}

class KnopHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        geklikt = true;
        waardeP1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // get another random number
        waardeP2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // get another random number
        repaint();

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to change the throwing player and switch it on each throw.
The easiest way to switch a boolean is.

```
switchBoolean = !switchBoolean;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to get rid of if-s. Try switch, it's more readable.

Player switching you can implement in a class which controls the game. Create a variable Player currentPlayer. Now create a while loop with some termination condition and after each dice throw change currentPlayer to other player.